# Where is the python version of Dataflow training course provided by Google GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am learning GCP **beam/pubsub/bigquery** now, there is a java version of example on Google:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/courses/streaming/process/sandiego/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/training/dataanalyst/sandiego

I wonder if there is a python equivalent anywhere?

Can anyone share your experience on how do you run a **pub/sub to load data into BigQuery table**?

Comment: Install the Python `apache_beam` package. There are numerous examples to study as part of the package in the `Lib/site-packages/apache_beam/examples` folder.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples or https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python

Comment: Thank you John/Enrique, I got it now, not "numerous" as per John said. :)